# A method to insert cell in the given tableview just as the argument?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am under huge impression of the new SDK I'm implementing and I just want to ask you... how did they do it?

```
NSInteger rowToDisplayInRead = 1;
NSIndexPath *pathForTeadsInRead = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowToDisplayInRead inSection:0];
NSString *pid = KTeadsAdPlacementId;
self.teadsAd = [[TeadsAd alloc] initInReadWithPlacementId:pid insertionIndexPath:pathForTeadsInRead repeatMode:NO tableView:self.tableView delegate:self];
```

Using this code, a new cell appears in the tableview. (Nothing left was set except of the "`[self.teadsAd load]`" function in `viewdidappear()`.

I didn't even increased number of rows in `numberOfRowsInSection` delegate).

How to do the same thing?

I couldn't find the terms connected to this operation, but it's great!

Can you help me where to find it?

Comment: Which library you are using ? can please explain more on this ?

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution would be to replace the `dataSource` in the tableView to one that returns the ad cell for chosen `indexPath` and proxies the "old" datasource for rest of the cells.

So dummy implementation of this would look like this:

```
@interface Example : NSObject<UITableViewDataSource>

- (instancetype)initWithTableView:(UITableView *)tableView indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

@property (nonatomic, strong) id<UITableViewDataSource> originalDataSource;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSIndexPath *insertionIndexPath;

@end
```

m file:

```
- (instancetype)initWithTableView:(UITableView *)tableView indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.insertionIndexPath = indexPath;
        self.originalDataSource = tableView.dataSource;
        tableView.dataSource = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSInteger numberOfRows = [self.originalDataSource tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];

    // the section that will contain injected cell
    if(self.insertionIndexPath.section == section) {
        return numberOfRows + 1;
    }

    // any other section
    return numberOfRows;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([indexPath isEqual:self.insertionIndexPath]){
        //return cell with an ad
    }

    if(indexPath.section == self.insertionIndexPath.section && indexPath.row > self.insertionIndexPath.row) {
        NSIndexPath *originalIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row - 1 inSection:indexPath.section];
        return [self.originalDataSource tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:originalIndexPath];
    }

    return [self.originalDataSource tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

You would also need to do the same for rest of the datasource and delegate methods and proxy them with updated index path to original datasource/delegate.